# "autoResizeDimensions" request for Google Sheets API doesn't work properly

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a script that performs some processing and outputs in google spreadsheets. After uploading data to the worksheet, I need to make columns resized to fit content automatically. As I researched API, the only way to do this is to use "autoResizeDimensions" API request.

Here is how the result of the request looks like (sorry, I had to corrupt the symbols):
[Result of executing API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59uxd.png)

As you can see, there is some space between actual "end of content in cell" and column border.

However, when I select columns in browser, open resize window and click on "fit to data" option, I receive the exactly what I need to get:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXcHD.png)

Could anyone, please, help me getting the pretty look of columns?

Thank you!

P.S. I am using Python 3.6.7 and module gspread 3.1.0. There is built-in method for running batch_update requests. Here is how I use it for uploading pandas dataframe to spreadsheet:

```
def clear_sheet(sheet):
    """Fill sheet with empty cells starting from B2"""
    empty_cells = []
    for col_index in range(10):
        for row_index in range(1000):
            empty_cells.append(Cell(row=row_index+2, col=col_index+2, 
                value=''))

    sheet.update_cells(empty_cells)


def upload_frame(sheet, frame):
    """Upload frame to sheet starting from B2"""
    frame_cells = []
    frame_as_list = frame.fillna('').values.tolist()
    for row_index, row in enumerate(frame_as_list):
        for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row):
            frame_cells.append(Cell(row=row_index+2, col=col_index+2, 
                 value=cell_value))

    sheet.update_cells(frame_cells)


def set_autoresize(sheet):
    """Set autoresize for first 11 columns of sheet"""
    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "autoResizeDimensions": {
                    "dimensions": {
                        "sheetId": sheet._properties['sheetId'],
                        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                        "startIndex": 0,
                        "endIndex": 11
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    sheet.spreadsheet.batch_update(body)

gc = gspread.authorize(CREDENTIALS)
report_worksheet = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)

update_all = False
current_sheet_titles = [sheet.title for sheet in report_worksheet.worksheets()]
print('Current sheets: {}'.format(current_sheet_titles))
for month, frame in monthly_frames.items():
    sheet_title = '{}-{}'.format(current_year, month)
    if sheet_title not in current_sheet_titles:
        print('Creating sheet {}'.format(sheet_title))
        new_sheet = report_worksheet.worksheet('Template').duplicate(insert_sheet_index=0, new_sheet_name=sheet_title)
        upload_frame(new_sheet, frame)
        set_autoresize(new_sheet)
    elif (frame['Billing Completed'] == 'No').values.any() or update_all:
        print('Updating sheet {}'.format(sheet_title))
        sheet = report_worksheet.worksheet(sheet_title)
        # Update sheet
        clear_sheet(sheet)
        upload_frame(sheet, frame)
        set_autoresize(sheet)
    else:
        print('Skipping sheet {}'.format(sheet_title))
```

There is montly_frames dict with the next structure:
'2020-05': report_frame
Some of the sheets are being updated (cleared, filled and run autoresize) and some of them are being created and then filled and autoresize is being run.

Hope that it makes clear :)

Comment: I think that to provide your current script for replicating your issue will help users think of the issue and solution.

Comment: There is some margin after the resize, but in my case is not as big as yours. As @Tanaike said, we would need to see your code.

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited my comment adding some code snippets. Hope that it makes things clear.

Comment: @Jescannellas I have edited my comment adding some code snippets. Hope that it makes things clear

Comment: Thank you for adding the script. When I saw it, I thought that the request body for `autoResizeDimensions` is correct. And also, I could confirm the same situation with your situation. I thought that the specification might have been changed. Because when I had tested this when `autoResizeColumns` method of Spreadsheet service was not released, such space couldn't be confirmed. For example, how about testing a script of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumns(1, 11)` with Google Apps Script? Unfortunately, I cannot find the clear solution soon. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Got back to this problem. Tried using google app script method that you advised. Unfortunately, it works just as API request leaving this space. Probably the only way is to write some function for calculating column widths based on the data that I insert and applying it using API request each time I update the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```py
def __gspread_set_autoresize(gspread_workbook, gspread_sheet_name,
                             start_index, end_index=None):
    if (end_index is None):
        end_index = start_index
    gspread_sheet_id = \
        gspread_workbook.worksheet(gspread_sheet_name)._properties['sheetId']
    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "autoResizeDimensions": {
                    "dimensions": {
                        "sheetId": gspread_sheet_id,
                        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                        "startIndex": start_index,
                        "endIndex": end_index
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    return gspread_workbook.batch_update(body)
```

where

```py
gspread_workbook = \
    gspread.service_account(filename="%s/%s" %
                            ("/home/user/.config/gspread",
                             "service_account.json"))\
    .open_by_key(gspread_id)
```

and `gspread_id` holds the gspread identifier, then

```py
__gspread_set_autoresize(gspread_workbook, 'SHEET NAME', 1, 12)
```

auto-resizes the first 12 columns in my sheet with name `SHEET NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Since gspread==3.4, you can resize columns with :

```
worksheet = gspread_workbook.worksheet(gspread_sheet_name)
worksheet.columns_auto_resize(start_index, end_index)
```